# How to make a image override on webcam input in php website

Tags: php, jquery, webcam

My college project includes creating a simple php page for people to virtually try out clothes. so i got  a solution that use flash and jquery and using webcam.snap() to capture image from webcam. But what if i want to override the webcam feed with a shirt pic and make people 'virtually try them out'.

Comment: Can you provide the code that renders the webcam image?

Comment: You need to try something first. You're always welcome to ask the community for help when you're stuck. No one is going to code a solution for you